# Cassandra update query didn't change data and didn't throw an error

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

Hello I am facing a problem when I am trying to execute a really simple update query in `cqlsh`

```
update "Table" set "token"='111-222-333-444' where uid='123' and "key"='somekey';
```

It didn't throw any error, but the value of the token is still the same. However, if I try the same query for some other field it works just fine:

```
update "Table" set "otherfield"='value' where uid='123' and "key"='somekey';
```

Any ideas why Cassandra can prevent updates for some fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the entry was inserted by client with incorrect clocks, or something like.  The data in Cassandra are "versioned" by write time that could be even in the future (depending on use case).  And when reading, Cassandra compares the write time of all versions of the specified column (there could be multiple versions in the data files on the disk), and selects one with highest write time.

You need to check the write time of that column value (use the [writetime](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWritetime.html) function) and compare with your current time:

```
select writetime(token) from Table where uid='123' and "key"='somekey';
```

the resulting value is in the microseconds.  You can remove last 3 digits, and use something like [this site](https://currentmillis.com/) to convert it into human-understandable time.

Comment: Thank you @alex you are completely right. Something happened which I have no idea why and we have a lot of fields in database now that are corrupted and has writetime in future. Is there any easy way of fixing this?

Comment: theoretically you can copy the data into a new table, using something like DSBulk or Spark, but this will break TTL if you're using it...

Comment: sounds scary :) also do you have any idea what could cause this problem? client, in this case, is PHP application and we didn't change anything in code whatsoever that could impact this. one of our application nodes on AWS got some hardware problems can it be that if application node had wrong date it could impact this?

Comment: usually it comes to the clocks on the client side - it's always recommended to have ntpd running